# Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4 when install phpmyadmin in centos 7

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, php7

How to fix the confliction when install phpmyadmin with PHP 7?
I have install PHP 7 and Httpd and last one I want to install phpmyadmin but I got this errors during I've install it.

```
 sudo yum install phpmyadmin
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/jkaluza/httpd24/epel-7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article 

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please create a bug on https://bugs.centos.org/

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror2.totbb.net
 * epel: epel.mirror.angkasa.id
 * extras: centos-hcm.viettelidc.com.vn
 * updates: centos-hcm.viettelidc.com.vn
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.4.15.7-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mysqli >= 5.3.7 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.7-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 5.3.7 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.7-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-gd >= 5.3.7 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.7-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-xmlwriter for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.7-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.7-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-tcpdf for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.7-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-php-gettext for package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.7-1.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-php-gettext.noarch 0:1.0.11-12.el7 will be installed
---> Package php-tcpdf.noarch 0:6.2.11-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-tidy for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-posix for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-bcmath for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
---> Package php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 0:6.2.11-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package php70w-gd.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.w7 will be installed
---> Package php70w-mbstring.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.w7 will be installed
---> Package php70w-mysql.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php70w-pdo(x86-64) for package: php70w-mysql-7.0.8-1.w7.x86_64
---> Package php70w-xml.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.w7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1 for package: php-bcmath-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.x86_64
---> Package php-process.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1 will be installed
---> Package php-tidy.x86_64 0:5.4.16-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtidy-0.99.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-tidy-5.4.16-4.el7.x86_64
---> Package php70w-pdo.x86_64 0:7.0.8-1.w7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libtidy.x86_64 0:0.99.0-31.20091203.el7 will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libzip.so.2()(64bit) for package: php-common-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libzip.x86_64 0:0.10.1-8.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php70w-common-7.0.8-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find a PHPMyAdmin package that doesn't depend on 5.4 version of PHP, but is prepared so that it depends on PHP7.

Comment: How to find that package.Should i uninstall this pages?

Comment: Google is a good tool for finding such a package. It might be that such a package does not exist. In that case you can try manual installation with the instructions provided in PHPMyAdmin main distribution.